# Reset mx:hslider value

Tags: flex4

I am new to flex and my question is how to reset mx hslider value with "reset" button.
here is a sample script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.SliderEvent;
            private var txtvalue:int = 0;
            protected function Focal_changeHandler(event:SliderEvent):void
            {
                txtvalue = Focal.value;
                if(txtvalue == 0)
                    Slider_txt.text = "Low";
                if(txtvalue == 1)
                    Slider_txt.text = "Middle";
                if(txtvalue == 2)
                    Slider_txt.text = "High";

            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:HSlider id="Focal" x="476" y="345" maximum="2" minimum="0" value="0" buttonMode="true" enabled="true" snapInterval="1" tickInterval="1" allowTrackClick="true" liveDragging="true" change="Focal_changeHandler(event)"/>
    <s:Label id="Slider_txt" x="472" y="319" text= "Low"/>
    <s:Button x="476" y="459" label="Reset" id="Res_btn"/>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you could do

```
<s:Button x="476" y="459" label="Reset" id="Res_btn" click="{Focal.value = 0}"/>
```

But since you'd need to update the text as well, it's better to do an own method for that:

```
<s:Button x="476" y="459" label="Reset" id="Res_btn" click="onResetClick()"/>
```

and in your code part:

```
protected function Focal_changeHandler(event:SliderEvent):void
{
    updateSliderText();
}

private function onResetClick():void
{
    Focal.value = 0;
    updateSliderText();
}

private function updateSliderText():void
{
    txtvalue = Focal.value;
    if (txtvalue == 0)
        Slider_txt.text = "Low";
    if (txtvalue == 1)
        Slider_txt.text = "Middle";
    if (txtvalue == 2)
        Slider_txt.text = "High";
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to mark it as "Correct" ;)